# How to make js/ python code send an SMS once when run

Tags: javascript, python, sms, qr-code

I and my friends are planning to make a small project for our school. So basically what it does is when a QR code is scanned, the code inside it will activate and send an SMS to a specified number with the current time. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this kind of article](https://www.fullstackpython.com/blog/send-sms-text-messages-python.html). I do recommend using another way to send messages, like Twitter for example, which has an easier-to-use API.